# artifacts are not in local repository error

Tags: java, maven, appfuse

I am trying to create a appfuse project using netbeans. I have added to following to the pom file:

```
mvn archetype:create -DarchetypeGroupId=org.appfuse.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=appfuse-modular-struts -DremoteRepositories=http://static.appfuse.org/releases -DarchetypeVersion=2.0.2 -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=myproject
```

I get the following error when I try to build the project:

> Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:myproject:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [org.appfuse:appfuse-struts:pom:3.5.0 (compile), org.appfuse:appfuse-service:jar:3.5.0 (compile), org.appfuse:appfuse-hibernate:jar:3.5.0 (compile), org.appfuse:appfuse-data-common:jar:3.5.0 (compile), commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4 (compile), org.subethamail:subethasmtp-wiser:jar:1.2 (test), org.directwebremoting:dwr:jar:2.0.10 (compile), net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-web:jar:2.0.4 (compile), net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.6.9 (compile), javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1 (provided), javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0 (provided), javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2 (compile), struts-menu:struts-menu:jar:2.4.3 (runtime), org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:jar:2.0 (compile), opensymphony:sitemesh:jar:2.4.2 (runtime), org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE (compile), org.tuckey:urlrewritefilter:jar:4.0.3 (compile), ro.isdc.wro4j:wro4j-core:jar:1.7.5 (compile), org.webjars:jquery-cookie:jar:1.3.1 (compile), org.webjars:bootstrap:jar:3.3.1 (compile), org.webjars:bootstrap-datepicker:jar:1.3.1 (compile), org.webjars:bootswatch-spacelab:jar:3.3.1+2 (compile), org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:jar:2.1 (runtime), org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:jar:2.1 (runtime), commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6 (compile), org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE (compile), org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.4 (compile), org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.4 (compile), org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:jar:1.3 (test), junit:junit:jar:4.12 (compile?), org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7 (compile), org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jcl:jar:2.1 (compile), org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.1 (compile), org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.1 (compile), org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.2.0.Beta1 (compile), mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.27 (compile), org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE (compile?)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:pom:3.3.2 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2/commons-lang3-3.3.2.pom. Return code is: 504 , ReasonPhrase:Gateway Timeout. -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's choking trying to download the pom file for commons-lang (at the bottom). Are you able to hit the URL to that POM file (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2/commons-lang3-3.3.2.pom from your local machine in the browser? I have run across a few cases where internal network issues sometimes cause problems with certain libraries.